# Correct adjectival form of the word "disperse"

Tags: adjectives, derivational-morphology

I am writing an article related to the ionosphere and I would like to ask what form of the word *disperse* is right in the sentence:

> A significant majority of the error can be easily removed using two or
> more frequencies due to the **disperse** nature of the ionosphere.

I looked at few dictionaries and googled the combination "disperse nature". [Here](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/disperse) is what I found:

> ▶adjective: Chemistry denoting a phase dispersed in another phase, as in a colloid. – derivatives
> dispersal *noun*,
>
> disperser *noun*,
>
> dispersible *adjective*
>
> dispersive *adjective*.

---

And for example http://www.yourdictionary.com/disperse-system

> **disperse system**
>
> A disperse system is a two-part system made up of microscopic particles and the medium in which they are suspended. (noun)

Here, if I am not mistaken, the word *disperse* is used as an adjective.

---

I am not an English native speaker and I have no sense in this. What is the right form for my sentence?

Comment: *Dispersive* is the appropriate adjective, but sentence "A significant majority of the error can be easily removed using two or more frequencies due to the dispersive nature of the ionosphere" nevertheless probably is incorrectly formed and should instead say "A significant majority of the error due to the dispersive nature of the ionosphere can be easily removed using two or more frequencies".

Comment: Thx : ) I will change it right away : )

Comment: Note, "a significant majority" is redundant; one instead says "much" or "most", "a majority", "a major part", "a significant amount", "a significant fraction", etc.

Comment: So the conclusion is: I should take English lessons : ) Thank you for this comment as well, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe *[dispersive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispersive)* is your best bet:

> 1: of or relating to dispersion *a dispersive medium*, *the dispersive
>   power of a lens*
>   2: tending to disperse

So you'd have

> A significant majority of the error can be easily removed using two or
>   more frequencies due to the **dispersive** nature of the ionosphere.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's it! If you Google _dispersive nature_ plenty of  scientific articles will pop up: ) Thx! (Now I am a little bit ashamed that I didn't try it before...)

Answer (score 1):

(-) Is the ionosphere, itself, disperse?
If yes, then because past participles can be adjectives, I would write "dispersed".
ex: "100% distilled water does not have a dispersed nature."

(-) Is the ionosphere not dispersed, but the ionosphere causes dispersion, then I would use "dispersive":
ex: "With regard to light diffraction, 100% distilled water has a dispersive nature."

Comment: Using *disperse* as in your first sentence is nonsense; to be grammatical it should be one of  *dispersed*,  *dispersive*, or *dispersible*.

Comment: If you don't think that past participles can function as adjectives, then I don't know what to say.

Comment: What I think about past participles is irrelevant because *disperse* is not a past participle.  Per [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disperse), *disperse* is present tense and its past participle is *dispersed*.  If you have a source to contrary, cite it.

Comment: dude. I don't see what you are reading: "100% distilled water does not have a dispersed nature." "Dispersed" modifies "nature". good luck.

Comment: That's not the first sentence.  What I meant by "the first sentence" is the question "Is the ionosphere, itself, disperse?".

Comment: "Is the ionosphere, itself, disperse?" is a predicate adjective in the form of an interrogative sentence. [main verb + article + subject + reflexive pronoun + adjective] The tenor of this forum surprises me. This feels like an engineering forum. I love it. Aggressiveness, not courtesy,  brings out the truth. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

"Disperse" is a suitable adjective; the opposite of "dense".

Comment: Hello, JohnH, and welcome to English Language & Usage. You can greatly strengthen this answer by including a definition of _disperse_ (from a recognized reference authority) that reinforces your position, rather than making a simple assertion without substantiation.

Comment: Indeed--although it may or may not be restricted to a technical usage in physics

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody suggested ['sparse'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sparse) as an alternate word.

> Thinly dispersed or scattered